# Как использовать progress bar если много файлов на загрузку?

Tags: c#

Доброй ночи, подскажите как использовать ProgressBar при загрузке множества файлов.
У меня всегда разный список ссылок и программа узнает об этом только тогда, когда я кликну по кнопке.
Мне приходит список ссылок и через WebClient я их скачиваю.
Я нашел примеры в гугле но там для одного файла.
Хотелось, что бы ProgressBar показывал информацию на основании количества файлов которое я качаю.

```
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    WebClient clinet;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = textBox1.Text;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
                clinet.DownloadFileAsync(uri, Application.StartupPath + "/" + filename);

            });
            thread.Start();
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clinet = new WebClient();
        clinet.DownloadProgressChanged += Clinet_DownloadProgressChanged;
        clinet.DownloadFileCompleted += Clinet_DownloadFileCompleted; 
    }

    private void Clinet_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Download Complete!!!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void Clinet_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {

            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            double receive = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double total = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double precentage = receive / total * 100;
            label1.Text = $"Downloaded { string.Format("{0:0.## }", precentage) }%";
            progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(precentage).ToString());
        }
        ));
    }
}
}
```

Соорудил такой вот код, но он качает только если один файл.

Comment: А два PrograssBar есть возможность использовать? Один для текущего файла, второй - общий. Либо вычислять размер всех файлов и складывать.

Comment: Можно и два. Просто я заметил одну вещь, при асинхронном методе загрузки, он качает почти моментально.
Файлы мелкие килобайт по 400.
А вот при обычном не async качает уже чуть дольше. Вот если бы не async как то прикрутить.